# Cannot allocate memory space in in AllocDoubleArray

Tags: c++, c, memory

I have a set of images that I iterate trough a C loop and I want to calculate a descriptor on them. The code is very simple:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

FILE *arq = NULL;
CImage *cimg=NULL;
Image *mask=NULL;
Image *gt=NULL;
CImage *rmask=NULL;
int  maxR, minR, r, relevance;

if (argc != 5) 
{       
     fprintf(stderr,"usage: extraction <image> <region mask> <groundtruth> <curve>\n");
     return(1);
}   

fprintf(stderr, "\nReading Image");  
cimg = ReadCImage(argv[1]);
fprintf(stderr, "\nPasso 2: Reading Segmentation");  
mask = ReadImage(argv[2]);
fprintf(stderr, "\nPasso 3: Reading Ground-Truth");  
gt = ReadImage(argv[3]); 
arq = fopen(argv[4], "a+");

maxR = MaximumValue(mask);
minR = MinimumValue(mask);

for(r=minR; r <= maxR; r++) 
{  
    relevance = isRelevant(gt, mask, r);
    rmask = createRegionImage(r, mask, cimg);
    Extraction(rmask,relevance,r,arq);

}

fclose(arq);
DestroyCImage(&cimg);
DestroyImage(&mask);
DestroyImage(&gt);  

return(0);
}
```

In other words, this code opens an image file and seeks for regions of this image. After that it extracts a feature from each of the image regions.

My problem is the fact that this code works for all image regions except one (26150). It returns the error 'Cannot allocate memory space in in AllocDoubleArray'. The gdb output is

```
Error:Cannot allocate memory space in in AllocDoubleArray

Program exited with code 0377.
```

The compilation is ok as you can see

```
rm ../bin/*
cd ../; make; cd app
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/me/code/descriptor/source'
echo "libtexturedescriptors.a built..."
libtexturedescriptors.a built...
make[1]: Leaving directory /home/me/code/descriptor/source'
gcc -O2 -Wall my_program.c -o ../bin   /my_program -I../include -L../lib -ltexturedescriptors -lm
```

Is this region big enough for my PC memory? anybody faced this error before? how to solve it?

Comment: On what operating system, with what compiler, with which libraries are you coding? Did you enable all warnings and debugging info during compilation? `AllocDoubleArray` is not a standard C function! And you should very probably `#include` some header files. Show also your compilation and linking command.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch 1-I am running it on linux gcc using some other libraries 2- I guess all warnings and debbuging info are given to me during compilation. 3- The code compiles ok. 4- Yes, I included other header files. What else do you need to help me? thank you.

Comment: So, set a breakpoint on the error message and find out what it's trying to allocate!

Comment: BTW, put the `\n` at the end (not the beginning) of `printf` format strings. And use your `gdb` debugger. Are you sure you got no warnings at all? Also, edit your question to tell much more about the used libraries and compilation command.